# OraOLEDB.Oracle provider not registered on local machine

Tags: c#, .net, sql, windows, visual-studio-2010

I just upgraded from `Win XP` to `Win 7`. A `.Net` application I wrote on my `XP` machine is throwing an exception now on my Win & machine.

```
        OleDbConnection _conn = new OleDbConnection(_conString);
        try
        {
            _conn.Open();
            return true;
        }
```

The error occurs when checking to see if there is an open DB connection - _conn.Open()

```
The 'OraOLEDB.Oracle' provider is not registered on the local machine.
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  The provider your trying to use is not registered.  Furthermore your code is not complete.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the `location` you installed the files in the `PATH variable for windows.`

If you use the install.bat file to install the files at C:\Oracle, you need to place the paths "C:\Oracle" and C:\Oracle\bin" in `the PATH variable`.

You can find this variable by `right-clicking` on `My computer` and `selecting Properties (for Windows Vista/7` `users, it's right clicking on Computer then properties then advanced system settings)`. Click on the `Advanced tab and click the Environment Variables button.` In the Systems variables list, you'll find the `PATH variable`

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the location I installed the files...

Comment: You serach on your machine your oracle files,